# How can I remove the search bar and footer added by the jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net).

I want to remove the search bar and footer (showing how many rows there are visible) that is added to the table by default. I just want to use this plugin for sorting, basically. Can this be done?

Comment: You could efficiently use `sDom` as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53885264/5729813

Comment: use `dom: 'lrtip'` option

Answer (score 673, accepted):

For **DataTables >=1.10**, use:

```js
$('table').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, info: false});
```

If you still want to be able to use the `.search()` function of this plugin, you will need to hide the search bar's html with the `dom` setting:

```js
$('table').dataTable({dom: 'lrt'});
```

The defaults are `lfrtip` or `<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>` (when `jQueryUI` is true), `f` char represents the filter (search) html in the dom, `ip` for the info and pagination (footer).

For **DataTables <1.10**, use:

```js
$('table').dataTable({bFilter: false, bInfo: false});
```

or using pure CSS:

```css
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }
```

Comment: As good as @antpaw comment is, and seems to work in most cases, it doesn't work if there is filtering going on for each column, like in this example :http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/col_filter.html . Be aware!

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks The example URL is broken: https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

Comment: I don't understand why this is accepted, since it doesn't answer the question. The problem was removing the search bar and the footer, not disabling searching entirely.

Comment: to completely remove footer you have to set `paging:false` and `info:false` , not just `paging:false`

Comment: adding to @user1563544's comment, is there any way to just hide the search bar and NOT disabling the functionality? (other than CSS tricks?)

Comment: @user1563544 You can remove the filter box by using the dom attribute - check out https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom and simply remove 'f' tag which is the filter box. Also you should resize some columns so that they add up to 12

Comment: Worked for me. I was using 'seach' as opposed to 'searching'. Docs actually state 'search' which clearly doesn't work.

Comment: WRONG ANSWER  - `searching: false` disables `search()` function for the DT at all

Comment: @UmairAyub Thank you, I've included a solution for this problem in my answer.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching

Comment: Wrong answer. this will disable the search function. It will ruin the project when individual column filtering is required.

Comment: beware that `lrt` will hide pagination, more info here https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Options

Answer (score 93):

Check out http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html for a list of features to show/hide.

What you want is to set "bFilter" and "bInfo" to false;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false
                 } );
} );
```

Comment: @Eric thank you its working for me, but i want to show "bPaginate" only i don't want to show "binfo" how i can implement if i did "bInfo" = false and "bPaginate"= true then both are showing

Comment: In the latest version of DataTables is just `{paging: false, info: false}`

Answer (score 47):

You can also not draw the header or footer at all by setting `sDom`:   http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

```
'sDom': 't'
```

will display JUST the table, no headers or footers or anything.

It's discussed some here: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2722/how-to-hide-empty-header-and-footer/p1

Comment: This should be added to antpaw's answer.  This affectively hides the filter and info placeholder divs still remaining when passing "bFilter": false, "bInfo": false.

Comment: This removes pagination in the footer. I don't think it's a good practice.

Comment: It's now called 'dom' and you can controll a lot more with this option. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. The other answers involving css and js tweaks are all hacks. If you want to use DataTables properly, this is how you do that. As an example, if you want to show all the bits and pieces (paging, page-length etc.) except for the search box, you would add a `dom` property with a value of `ltipr` see https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 27):

If you are using custom filter, you might want to hide search box but still want to enable the filter function, so `bFilter: false` is not the way. Use `dom: 'lrtp'` instead, default is `'lfrtip'`. Documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 12):

```
var table = $("#datatable").DataTable({
   "paging": false,
   "ordering": false,
   "searching": false
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A quick and dirty way is to find out the class of the footer and hide it using jQuery or CSS:

```
$(".dataTables_info").hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

As said by @Scott Stafford `sDOM` is the most apropiated property to show, hide or relocate the elements that compose the DataTables. I think the `sDOM` is now outdated, with the actual patch this property is now `dom`.

This property allows to set some class or id to an element too, so you can stylish easier.

Check the oficial documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

This example would show only the table:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "dom": 't'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using themeroller:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .fg-toolbar { display: none; }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, This pointed me in the right direction.  I didnt want to hide the header as well so i just wanted the footer.  ui-corner-bl and ui-corner-br classes are only applied to the footer so i used either one to get the footer wrapper........            $(".ui-corner-bl").hide();

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nametable').DataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false
    });
});
</script>
```

in your datatable constructor

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20006/how-to-remove-cross-icon-in-search-box

Comment: this answer doesn't have any link to any doc, and you did not provide a working answer

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by simply changing the configuration:

```
$('table').dataTable({
      paging: false, 
      info: false
 });
```

But to hide the empty footer; this piece of code does the trick:

```
 $('table').dataTable({
      paging: false, 
      info: false,

      //add these config to remove empty header
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sDom": 'lfrtip'

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you can add to `sDom` element to your code, top search bar is hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
"sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
 } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just a reminder you can't initialise `DataTable` on the same `<table>` element twice.**

If you encounter same issue then you can set `searching` and `paging` false while initializing DataTable on your HTML `<table>` like this

```
 $('#tbl').DataTable({
    searching: false, 
    paging: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
       'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sDom attribute. Code looks something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        'sDom': '"top"i'
                 } );
} );
```

İt hides search and pager box.

Answer (score 1):

> As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation
>   options using HTML5 data-* attributes.

-[dataTables documentation: HTML5 data-* attributes - table options](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html)

So you can specify `data-searching="false" data-paging="false" data-info="false"` on the `table`. For example, this table will not allow searching, apply paging, or show the information block:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" data-searching="false" data-paging="false" data-info="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th data-orderable="false">Avatar</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8edcff60cdcca2ad650758fa524d4990?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; visibility: visible;"></td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/98fe9834dcca2ad650758fa524d4990?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; visibility: visible;"></td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        ...[ETC]...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/17v94f2s/](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/17v94f2s/).

The advantage to this approach is that it allows you to have a standard dataTables call (ie, `$('table.apply_dataTables').DataTable()`) while being able to configure the dataTables options table-by-table.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to hide the search form for example because you have column input filters or may be because you already have a CMS search form able to return results from the table then all you have to do is inspect the form and get its id - (at the time of writing this, it looks as such`[tableid]-table_filter.dataTables_filter`). Then simply do `[tableid]-table_filter.dataTables_filter{display:none;}` retaining all other features of datatables.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me #table is a Id of table

```
$('#table').dataTable({searching: false, paging: false, info: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me;

You can remove search bar using this attribute on table : data-searching="false"

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1920651/14267427).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_table').DataTable({
   "iDisplayLength": 100,
   "searching": false, 
   "paging": false,
   "info": false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide them via css:

```
#example_info, #example_filter{display: none}
```

Comment: Not 'wrong', merely different.  It depends on whether you want to hide all instances (by class, as in your answer), or a particular instance (by ID, as in mine).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by assigning footer an id and then styling using css :

```
    <table border="1" class="dataTable" id="dataTable_${dtoItem.key}" >
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tfoot>
    <tr>
            <th id="FooterHidden"></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>

    <tr>

                <td class="copyableField"></td>

    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

then styling using css :

```
#FooterHidden{
   display: none;
}
```

As above mentioned ways aren't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is:

```
<th data-searchable="false">Column</th>
```

You can edit only the table you have to modify, without change common CSS or JS.

Answer (score 0):

No filtering input control. (https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

```
    /* Results in:
        {length}
        {processing}
        {table}
        {information}
        {pagination}
    */
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "dom": 'lrtip'
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {          
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          dom: 'lrt',
          paging: false,
          info: false,
          "search": {
            "caseInsensitive": true
          }
        });
      $('#txtSearch').on('keyup change', function() {
        dataTable_Search($(this).val());
      });

      $('#btnClear').on('click', function() {
        $('#txtSearch').val('');
        dataTable_Search('');
      });

      function dataTable_Search(v) {
        table.search(v).draw();
      }
    });
```

Fiddler : https://jsfiddle.net/godlymathew/mbn78xdh/