# Need to delete the search field using datatable jquery

Tags: php, jquery, csv, datatables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there anyway to remove the Search bar and footer in the jquery datatable plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1920600/352449)

I am very new to implement datatable for sorting my column.
Now, if I click on the column header, the record is sorting fine ascending and descending order. But I don't want any search field over there, as I have one customize search box. Now I am not finding how to remove the search option. Also, After getting record, I want to export the record in a csv file. According to the current record (ascending or descending order) how to do that?
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the search bar and footer added by the jQuery DataTables plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920600/how-can-i-remove-the-search-bar-and-footer-added-by-the-jquery-datatables-plugin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the search field from your table:

**JQUERY**

```
$('table').dataTable({"bFilter": false});
```

**CSS**

```
.dataTables_filter {
  display: none;
}
```

You can read all about personalizing the jQuery DataTables [here!](http://datatables.net/examples/)

Comment: You forgot about sDom! sDom will prevent whatever you want from rendering, while maintaining the functionality (unlike setting bFilter to false, which disables filtering altogether).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "searching": false
});
```