# jQuery DataTables: hide search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I seem not able to hide DataTables default search bar. So far, I have tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920600/how-can-i-remove-the-search-bar-and-footer-added-by-the-jquery-datatables-plugin) thread, but setting `bFilter:false` disables filtering entirely, so my search boxes in the footer simply do not work any longer.

I have put up [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg78o9z3/)

My HTML:

```
<thead>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>apple</td>
                <td>fruit</td>
                <td>red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>banana</td>
                <td>fruit</td>
                <td>yellow</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>carrot</td>
                <td>vegie</td>
                <td>red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>potato</td>
                <td>vegie</td>
                <td>brown</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</tbody>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
  $('#mytable tfoot th').each( function (i) {
        let title = $('#mytable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" data-index="'+i+'" />' );
    } );
  $( table.table().container() ).on( 'keyup', 'tfoot input', function () {
    table
      .column( $(this).data('index') )
      .search( this.value )
      .draw();
  } );
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the search bar and footer added by the jQuery DataTables plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920600/how-can-i-remove-the-search-bar-and-footer-added-by-the-jquery-datatables-plugin)

Comment: I have mentioned in my post, that provided solution doesn't work for me because, it disables filtering not only with search bar, but with table bottom search boxes either, which I would like to keep.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to adjust sDom attribute of your DataTable accordingly:
`let table = $('#mytable').DataTable({sDom: 'lrtip'});`
That's supposed to hide search box without disabling filtering feature.
Also, you might want to check out [official reference](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom) doc regarding the subject.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks. Updated my fiddle according to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks so much.
To do this via HTML data attributes, simly add `data-s-dom="lrtip"` to the `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 11):

## Data table provides customization options to show and hide elements and also custom elements. We can use **dom** values to customize:

```
 l - length changing input control
    **f - filtering input**
    t - The table
    i - Table information summary
    p - pagination control
    r - processing display element

    **f is for filter , so we can remove it.**

        $('#example').dataTable( {
          "dom": 'lrtip'
        } );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let table = $('#mytable').DataTable({sDom: 'lrtip'});
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this class in your css - `.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }`

The live instance -

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    $('#mytable tfoot th').each(function (i) {
        let title = $('#mytable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" data-index="' + i + '" />');
    });
    $(table.table().container()).on('keyup', 'tfoot input', function () {
        table.column($(this).data('index'))
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<tbody>
    <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>apple</td>
                <td>fruit</td>
                <td>red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>banana</td>
                <td>fruit</td>
                <td>yellow</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>carrot</td>
                <td>vegie</td>
                <td>red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>potato</td>
                <td>vegie</td>
                <td>brown</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **DataTable** from https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/ , inside **ngOnInit(),** you can set the **Searching** prop to **false** inside *this.dtOptions.*

*Like this:*

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
ajax: or httpClient,


then you set, searching: false
       }
}
```